# An adjective for someone who likes sweets?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am writing something and want know, is there a particular word I can use to describe a sweet thief or a person who likes to eat too many sweets?

I'm looking for an adjective.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. I've added the single-word-request tag. Please review the [tag info](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for hints about what this sort of question requires. In particular, are you looking for word with disapproving overtones? A word implying admiration of the person's tolerance for sugar?

Comment: There is such a thing as a chocoholic, so why not a sugarholic, or sucroseholic, or fructoseholic? How about sugarmaniac? In other words, you may have to come up with a neologism on this one!

Comment: A person who prefers sweet things can be said to be "sweet-toothed".

Answer (score 4):

Someone who has a particular fondness or even a craving for sweets is said to have **a sweet tooth**.

If you need an adjective, you can say that person is **sweet-toothed**, as mentioned by WS2 in one of the comments.

> - [sweet-tooth](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sweet+tooth) (noun) - "a strong liking for sweet foods"

Examples from literature:

- "And I still had a sweet tooth, and on privy occasions when there was no man to see, bought candy and blissfully devoured it."
- "...the situation always arises when my goal of sticking to a dessert-free eating plan gets outdone by my sweet tooth; yes, the sweets always triumph."

Comment: Sorry for the lack of Information.... I was in a hurry and kinda didn't realize that I didn't explain it fully.....  But thank You for the information!